# XCode 4.1 project displays blank view on app launch

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

I have a project which was previously developed in Xcode 4.3.2, but when I try to run it on a device using Xcode 4.1, I get a blank screen, but I am able to print all the log messages and also able to hit the breakpoints. What might be wrong?
The project also makes use of some third party libraries.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try cleaning before building? Any error or warning?

Comment: i think give the Referance Outlet from xib to your view,try it may its work...

Comment: I tried cleaning up, also checked for reference outlets, everything's fine but, still not able to troubleshoot.
I am not making use of storyboard.